# HTML5 open iPhone or Android phone camera

Tags: iphone, camera

I'm currently deciding what way to build my Iphone/Android app. I just need to know how to open the iPhone/Android phone camera using HTML5/Javascript etc or whether it can even be done outside of building a native app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what tool you're using, but here's the phonegap answer: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks heaps for the reply, I appreciate it.

Comment: glad I could help. you can accept the answer so that it appears as a solved question

Comment: Not working for me. I am using Firefox on Android Galaxy S with 2.1

Comment: the "using firefox" is the issue...phonegap will wrap your HTML in some native code (Android, iOS, etc), so you'll have an app, not a page you view in firefox